# IDE Documentation - Documenting modelFactory()

Tags: php, netbeans, code-documentation

I'm curious if it's possible for me to document my `modelFactory()` so it's accessible via the doc helper tooltip as you're developing in Netbeans.  My models pass through modelFactory() so I can just do.....

```
$item = modelFactory('item')->getBy('user_count > 8');
```

and it'll give me an array of models or just 1 object depending on if there are multiple results.  It really condenses my code a lot.  The problem is when other developers start using this, I'd like for it to know which functions are available to `$item`.  Keep in mind that while this time it's an "item" model, next time it could be a user, blog post, or whatever else we need.

Is it possible to document this functionality for NetBeans?  I know if I do `$item = new Item();` it'll be able to recognize what's available.

**update**

The piece I'm looking for is how to tell my IDE that the output of ModelFactory is an $item model, so it knows where to look for the method documentation.

Comment: most ide's i've worked with know how to parse phpDoc comments, usualy you have to keep the file where the class sits open, however most ide's allow you to parse tose headers, worth a try

Answer (score 0):

In our PHP project we use PHPDocumentor (http://www.phpdoc.org/) for our documentation.

I works well with netbeans by the way.

Answer (score 0):

The @var PHPDoc comment is what you want. eg...

```
/**
 * @var core\SuperItemModel $item
 */
$item = modelFactory('item')->getBy('user_count > 8');
// the IDE will know that $item is of type core\SuperItemModel now...
```

Comment: Gotcha... is it possible to just somehow document that modelFactory() always looks as a specified folder rather than having to add this comment every time I use a model.

Comment: You can add some helper function to your modelFactory, or some other class where you are creating the objects (eg in your controller class). eg, add a getItemModel() function, and specify the type of the return value in the function comment. Now you can use `$item = $this->getItemModel()->getBy('blar');`